# if test on x strings that has to be unique - A more effective way?

Tags: c#, if-statement, comparison, compare, string-comparison

I have many strings that i need to if test that are all unique. If one of them equals another one the if test has to fail. In this example i will use 4 strings, but in reality it is way more than this.

```
string a = "a";
string b = "b";
string c = "c";
string d = "d";
```

One way to "solve this" is by doing a comparison on every single one. Like this:

```
if (a == b || a == c || a == d || b == c || b == d || c == d)
{
      throw new Exception("None of the strings can be equal");
}
```

However, I am looking for a more effective/smart way of doing this.

Anyone got any suggestions?

Comment: It matters a lot in what form you have those strings. Is it really as separate vairables? Please be precise.

Answer (score 1):

```
private bool UniqueCheck(params string[] items)
{
    return UniqueCheck((IEnumerable<string>)items);
}
private bool UniqueCheck(IEnumerable<string> items)
{
    var hs = new HashSet<string>();

    foreach (var item in items)
        if (!hs.Add(item))
            return false;

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like everyone else suggested you can make a HashSet  I would make a helper method.

```
static bool AreStringsUnique(params string[] toCompare)
{
    var hashTable = new HashSet<string>(toCompare);
    return hashTable.Count == toCompare.Length;
}
```

Then you can call it with any number of strings and let the compiler make the array for you.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method would be the one mentally you do when you look at this - put everything in a sequence and check for duplicates.

first, sequence it all. If it's "way more than 4" strings, consider putting it into a collection from the get go.

```
var strings = new string[] { "a", "b", "c", "d" };
```

Once you have a string[], you can perform [Linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) [operations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable_methods%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on it, since string[] inherits from IEnumerable

---

This would be my first implementation, simply filtering out duplicates and seeing if the list shrinks

```
if(strings.Distinct().Count() < strings.Count)
    throw new Exception("None of the strings can be equal");
```

---

And here's another, using the [GroupBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method and seeing if any group has more than one element.

```
if(strings.GroupBy(s => s).Any(g => g.Count() > 1))
    throw new Exception("None of the strings can be equal");
```

and, with some tweaking, this can even tell you which key has been duplicated

```
var groupedStrings = string.GroupBy(s => s);
var errorGroup = groupedStrings.FirstOrDefault(g => g.Count() > 1);
if(errorGroup != null)
    throw new Exception(string.Format("Duplicate string \"{0}\" detected. None of the strings can be equal!", errorGroup.Key));
```